# Multiple G Suite Accounts

Tags: google-apps, google-workspace

I freelance for many clients and handle development and web hosting myself. Many of my clients want professional business email so I usually set them up with G Suite (sometimes MS Office 365 Business).

Currently, I've made a new G Suite account per domain and added their employee users that way. (some have multiple related domains so I'll keep them all together in that one account).

It's becoming hard to manage all these logins though and I was thinking would it make more sense to add all of my freelance clients domains to my business's G Suite account and manage their users that way?

Example: I have my `example.com` domain and main user is `me@example.com`

Three of my clients have `domain1.example`, `domain2.example` and `domain3.example` with multiple users. Can I add all three of theses to my `@example.com` G Suite account and manage their userbase that way?

Or should I stick to separate G Suite accounts for each freelance client?

Comment: I help manage 12 different school districts that use G Suite. The hesitation I have with doing this will be when you get dropped from one of your clients. Having to remove them from your top-level organization and provide documentation for admin logins, billing, etc would be a brain-numbing task.

Comment: @SeanRussell So would you recommend a seperate G Suite Admin account for each then?

Comment: Most definitely. Here is a link detailing some of the limitations: https://support.google.com/a/answer/182081

Comment: @SeanRussell ahh thanks for all the help! Makes much more sense now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a link detailing some of the limitations: support.google.com/a/answer/182081